# Peoplecode to hide column from a grid

Tags: peoplesoft

I am trying to hide a Column from a grid using Peoplecode, but the column comes from a subpage. I tried using the following code.

```
GetGrid(Page.PAGE_NAME, "GRID_NAME").GetColumn("COLUMN_FIELDNAME").Visible = False;
```

This didnt work. Can anyone help me with this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the name of the parent page and not the subpage in the GetGrid call. The code should be on the Activate event of the parent page.